# UI resizing when the virtual keyboard is opened on Codename One apps

Tags: codenameone

This question is referred only to Codename One apps.

Why do keyboards resize the UI on Android native apps and Javascript apps (only when run on Android) and don't have that effect on iOS native apps?

Can this default behavior be changed in our Codename One apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the native behavior of Android as you can see from the behavior in the browser. There isn't much we can do about it.

The solution is to make the UI scrollable which means everything will be resizable and behave more consistently in iOS/Android.