# Keep the Toolbar visible when the VKB is open

Tags: codenameone

This question is related to [Form with the VKB always open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811793/form-with-the-vkb-always-open): I would like to keep the VKB open while the Toolbar should remain visible. This should be the normality on Android, but it's not so on iOS.

How can I do that with Codename One? Other chatting apps keep the `Toolbar` (or something that has an UI equivalent to the `Toolbar`) open while the VKB is open even in iOS. Thank you

Screenshots:

- [Android - VKB closed - Toolbar visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFYt.png)
- [Android - VKB open - Toolbar not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0udkh.png)
- [Android - VKB open - Toolbar visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWnY.png)
- [iOS - VKB closed - Toolbar visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b5T0.png)
- [iOS - VKB open - Toolbar not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPRzk.png)

Comment: AFAIK there's no code that explicitly hides the toolbar in relation to the VKB but I might be unaware of something. Do you have screenshots of the problem?

Comment: I edited my question adding screenshots. Note that on iOS the opening of the VKB always hides the Toolbar, while on Android it depends on the contentPane scrolling when opening the VKB.

Comment: Have you tried setting bottomPaddingEditingMode to true on the form?  https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Form.html#setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode-boolean-

Comment: I tried `bottomPaddingEditingMode`, but this doesn't help neither in Android nor in iOS. I suspect that my question is related to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972808/ui-resizing-when-the-virtual-keyboard-is-opened-on-codename-one-apps Moreover, I use a Form inside another Form (the shown toolbar is owned by the inner Form), but I don't know if it's relevant for my question.

Comment: @stevehannah Solved: because I have a Form inside a Form, the solution is `setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);` both on outer form and inner form.