# Prevent TextField or TextArea from showing the "Done" button

Tags: codenameone

As you can note in the screenshots of the question [Keep the Toolbar visible when the VKB is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814185/keep-the-toolbar-visible-when-the-vkb-is-open), the VKB has a "Done" button. I don't want it, it's superfluous in this case (I already have a "Send" button on the right of the `TextField`), but I didn't find any code to prevent it from being displayed in Android and iOS.

On the Codename One developer guide, it's written how to customize the "Done" button on Android (section "[Action Button Client Property](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_action_button_client_property)") and how to hide the VKB toolbar on iOS (section "[Next and Done on iOS](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_next_and_done_on_ios)"), but there is no indication to hide the "Done" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either this globally:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("iosHideToolbar", "true");
```

or this for the specific component

```
textField.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", "true");
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work, because it doesn't prevent the showing of the "Done" button (on iOS). Moreover, my question is about suppressing the "Done" (or "Send") button both on iOS and Android.

Comment: Send on Android it builtin to the keyboard I don't think it can be suppressed. You can also use the back button there to fold the keyboard. On iOS this should work AFAIK I don't see how this can fail but maybe there's a bug there

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. If I understood correctly what it is written in the developer guide, the iOS VKB can appear with toolbar (https://www.codenameone.com/img/developer-guide/components-textfield-vkb-next.png) or without toolbar (https://www.codenameone.com/img/developer-guide/components-textfield-vkb-done.png): in the first case there is a "Next" button, in the second case there is a "Done" button. The build hint you suggested is for the second case. But I'm asking how to avoid at all both "Next" and "Done" buttons, possibly having a "return" button for new lines in the text input.

Comment: This hides both buttons. If you want a return button instead of a Done button you need to enable multiline mode in the text field using `setSingleLineTextArea(false)`

Comment: Solved: `textField.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", "true");` alone doesn't do what I asked, but  `textField.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", "true");` and `textField.setSingleLineTextArea(false);` together hide the "Done" button (both on iOS and Android), as I requested.